# EQL-PS4000 Fail Over test?

Tags: networking, storage, storage-area-network, dell-equallogic

This is been confusing me, I need to demo a controller failure. The PS4000 will only kick over to the secondary controller on physical failure. So link state will not work. Other that me tearing into the SAN and disconnecting the controller is there any way I can prove this for my peace of mind ? or do I just throw it into production hoping Dell did a good job on the Q&A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most SANs controller link failure is also handled by the MPIO mechanism the same as if the controller went pop - so, and I don't know PS4K's well, couldn't you just disconnect one controller's cabling?

Comment: I would but I know if something was to go wrong with the SAN it would be when i have the case cracked open. :) I guess for $40,000 i hope that controller kicks in. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you issue a restart from group manager, it will fail over between controllers, but you may want to verify with EQL support. I know that during a firmware upgrade, this is definitely the case.